# Modal pop up not getting displayed properly

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog

I have created the modal dialog box using the following javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function popThisUp()
    {
        var options = {
            url: "http://somehost/SitePages/View.aspx?IsDlg=1",
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            title: "My First Modal Dialog",
        };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnDialogDemo" runat="server" OnClientClick="popThisUp()" Text="Click here" />
```

I want to display my view site page or any page in the modal pop up on click of button but my modal dialog pops up for a second and then just closes on its own. I don't understand what is the problem here. Please help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `return false;` to avoid the postback caused by your asp button

```
 function popThisUp()
{
    var options = {

        url: "http://somehost/SitePages/View.aspx?IsDlg=1",

        width: 600,

        height: 300,

        title: "My First Modal Dialog",

    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    return false;
}
```

OR 
use html button control so that there is no postback from the page

`<input type='button' id="btnDialogDemo" onclick="popThisUp()" value="Click here"/>`